# Idiomatic way to perform a conditional transformation

Tags: scala

I have an object `x`. I am going to perform a series of transformation on it. This can easily be expressed as

```
x.transformA.transformB.transformC
```

However, before each transformation, I should also check for a condition. Only if the condition is true should I perform the transformation. I have two way to express this. The first is to define x as a var.

```
var x = anObject
if (x.condA) x = x.transformA
if (x.condB) x = x.transformB
if (x.condC) x = x.transformC
// final result in x
```

Alternatively, to avoid var, I define a series of intermediate variables

```
val x0 = anObject
val x1 = if (x0.condA) x0.transformA else x0
val x2 = if (x1.condB) x1.transformB else x1
val x3 = if (x2.condC) x2.transformC else x2
// final result in x3
```

This seems to be quite cumbersome, even error prone when I cut and paste the lines. Is there a more idiomatic way to express this?

Comment: The type of the object never changes? From the expressions above, `xi.transform` is the same type as `xi`

Comment: How about a fold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to express a series of conditional transformations as a composition of `Function`s. That way each transformation can be declared independently, and reused to build new tranformations.

As an example:

```
val ta: MyClass => MyClass = {case x if x.condA => x.transformA
                              case x => x}
val tb: MyClass => MyClass = {case x if x.condB => x.transformB
                              case x => x}
val tc: MyClass => MyClass = {case x if x.condC => x.transformC
                              case x => x}
```

Then we can compose those to form our transformation:

```
val transformation = ta andThen tb andThen tc
val transformedObj =  transformation(x)
```

We can see above that we are repeating the same pattern over and over again. To avoid that, we could make a function that creates our partial functions, reducing the boilerplate code:

```
def mkTf[T](cond: T => Boolean, transf: T => T): T => T = {
  case x if cond(x) => transf(x)
  case x => x
}
```

Then we can rewrite our composition as:

```
val transformation = mkTf[MyClass](_.condA,_.transformA) andThen
                     mkTf[MyClass](_.condB,_.transformB) andThen
                     mkTf[MyClass](_.condC,_.transformC)
```

Comment: What is the need for `PartialFunction`s ? `Function` works fine here, since it is defined for every `x: T`.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet You're absolutely right. I started answering with the idea of   adding the identity case as a `PartialFunction` fall back (`orElse`) but then got into another thought. Adapted the answer accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! It saves me from having a bunch of intermediate variables.